# Java HmacSHA256 with key

Tags: java, swift, sha256, hmac

i have tried several links from stackoverflow to get HmacSHA256 with key to work with java, but i always get

```
 func check(body: String) -> String {
    let hash = body.hmac(HMACAlgorithm.sha256, key: Router.sigKey)
    print("SIG: " + Router.sigKey)
    print("result of hash. \(hash)")
    return hash
}
```

This function returns hash with key from given String. 
Key was: 0393e944ee8108bb66fc9fa4f99f9c862481e9e0519e18232ba61b0767eee8c6

String was: example

Result is: 27effb76c97022497e25d3a5d7e823462f212a82d9ebba35f179071568b0c335

When i use [this](https://www.freeformatter.com/hmac-generator.html#ad-output) website to check if my SHA256 is good with the same key, it returns same answer, so i know my code in swift is good. But when i try to do it in java, here is the source code.

```
public static String HMAC_SHA(){
    try {
        String secret = "0393e944ee8108bb66fc9fa4f99f9c862481e9e0519e18232ba61b0767eee8c6";
        String message = "example";
        Mac sha256_HMAC = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
        SecretKeySpec secret_key = new SecretKeySpec(secret.getBytes(), "HmacSHA256");
        sha256_HMAC.init(secret_key);
        String hash = android.util.Base64.encodeToString(sha256_HMAC.doFinal(message.getBytes()), Base64.URL_SAFE);
        return new String(Hex.encodeHex(hash.getBytes()));
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

It returns this: 4a2d5f3764736c77496b6c2d4a644f6c312d676a526938684b6f4c5a36376f3138586b4846576977777a553d0a

Which is not even similar to the swift output. How can i achieve the same result with java from the swift code above, it would be helpful a lot!

Comment: You should never use String.getBytes() without an explicit charset. Compare the actual bytes you use as input in Swift and Java application.

Comment: @vanje I will try it now, and check if ti was a problem.

Comment: @vanje Which charset should i use ?

Comment: It doesn't matter, but you should use the same on each system. E.g. "Cp1252" is for Windows-ANSI or try "UTF-8".

Comment: @vanje I have tried UTF-8. But it displays same hash as without UTF-8. Any other idea what could help me ?

Comment: (1) for some/much data charset can be an issue but for the actual string here `example` it is not (2) your swift just displays the result in hex, but your java encodes to base64 and then the base64 to hex, which is both extremely silly and inconsistent; omit the base64 and you get the same result (although I suspect that key was _intended_ to be treated as hex, which you didn't do in either case)

Answer (score 10):

```
    String key = "0393e944ee8108bb66fc9fa4f99f9c862481e9e0519e18232ba61b0767eee8c6";
    Mac sha256_HMAC = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
    sha256_HMAC.init(new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), "HmacSHA256"));
    byte[] result = sha256_HMAC.doFinal("example".getBytes());
    System.out.println (DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(result));
    // ONLY CONVERT TO HEX (= SWIFT) NOT FIRST TO BASE64
```

result as requested

```
 27EFFB76C97022497E25D3A5D7E823462F212A82D9EBBA35F179071568B0C335
```

Answer (score -1):

Your key contains values greater then the value 127 and, `Mac` and `SecretKeySpec` use `byte`s, which in Java can contain values from -128 to 127.

---

In the HmacSHA256 algorithm, the key is interpreted as a string of hexadecimal values. In the case of your secret, the decimal values of this key are:
`3,147,233,68,238,129,8,187,102,252,159,164,249,159,156,134,36,129,233,224,81,158,24,35,43,166,27,7,103,238,232,198`

As you can see, some of them have a value over 127. When creating the `SecretKeySpec` object and while doing calculations within the `Mac` class, Java uses `byte[]` to store this and related sequences. In Java, a `byte` can contain values from -128 to 127, which means that when storing this secret, the values > 127 will "flip" and will make sure the calculations following this will not go as you'd expect.

In the Swift case (and with C++, Ruby, and other languages), the conversion from hex to byte occurs without losing the actual value.

Comment: I now see the following answer, which gives even more detail: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47797100/java-vs-golang-for-hotp-rfc-4226

Comment: The problem here is the call to `getBytes()`. The `secret` String should be parsed from hexadecimal, which is a completely different thing. In the question you linked it's done correctly with `decodeHex`.

Comment: This is wrong. JVM treats `byte` as signed, but it's easy to make it unsigned by masking it and that's exactly what all JCE code does, and produces the correct result. In _your_ code you should also do it correctly. @Kayaman: in the other Q yes; here the key looks hex but the swift code did NOT treat it as such, and the actual cause of the difference was double-encoding the output

Comment: @Kayaman I'm gonna need to evaluate in my usecase I was led to this conclusion. Thanks for the pointers.