# Java vs. Golang for HOTP (rfc-4226)

Tags: java, go, cryptography, sha512

I'm trying to implement HOTP (rfc-4226) in Golang and I'm struggling to generate a valid HOTP. I can generate it in java but for some reason my implementation in Golang is different. Here are the samples:

```
public static String constructOTP(final Long counter, final String key)
        throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, DecoderException, InvalidKeyException {
    final Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA512");

    final byte[] binaryKey = Hex.decodeHex(key.toCharArray());

    mac.init(new SecretKeySpec(binaryKey, "HmacSHA512"));
    final byte[] b = ByteBuffer.allocate(8).putLong(counter).array();
    byte[] computedOtp = mac.doFinal(b);

    return new String(Hex.encodeHex(computedOtp));
}
```

and in Go:

```
func getOTP(counter uint64, key string) string {
    str, err := hex.DecodeString(key)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    h := hmac.New(sha512.New, str)
    bs := make([]byte, 8)
    binary.BigEndian.PutUint64(bs, counter)
    h.Write(bs)
    return base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(h.Sum(nil))
}
```

I believe the issue is that the Java line: `ByteBuffer.allocate(8).putLong(counter).array();` generates a different byte array than the Go line: `binary.BigEndian.PutUint64(bs, counter)`.

In Java, the following byte array is generated: `83 -116 -9 -98 115 -126 -3 -48` and in Go: `83 140 247 158 115 130 253 207`.

Does anybody know the difference in the two lines and how I can port the java line to go?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `byte` type in Java is signed, it has a range of `-128..127`, while in Go `byte` is an alias of `uint8` and has a range of `0..255`. So if you want to compare the results, you have to shift negative Java values by `256` (add `256`).

*Tip: To display a Java `byte` value in an unsigned fashion, use: `byteValue & 0xff` which converts it to `int` using the 8 bits of the `byte` as the lowest 8 bits in the `int`. Or better: display both results in hex form so you don't have to care about sign-ness...*

Adding 256 to your negative Java byte values, the output is **almost** identical to Go's: the last byte is off by 1:

```
javabytes := []int{83, -116, -9, -98, 115, -126, -3, -48}
for i, b := range javabytes {
    if b < 0 {
        javabytes[i] += 256
    }
}
fmt.Println(javabytes)
```

Output is:

```
[83 140 247 158 115 130 253 208]
```

So the last byte of your Java array is `208` while Go's is `207`. I'm guessing your `counter` is incremented once somewhere else in your code which you haven't posted.

What differs is that in Java you return the hex encoded result while in Go you return the Base64 encoded result (they are 2 different encodings giving entirely different results). As you confirmed, in Go returning `hex.EncodeToString(h.Sum(nil))` the results match.

*Tip #2: To display Go's bytes in a signed fashion, simply convert them to `int8` (which is signed) like this:*

```
gobytes := []byte{83, 140, 247, 158, 115, 130, 253, 207}
for _, b := range gobytes {
    fmt.Print(int8(b), " ")
}
```

This outputs:

```
83 -116 -9 -98 115 -126 -3 -49
```

Comment: wow - TIL! what would the inverse operation be? (taking the Go version and creating the java version). Thanks a lot!

Comment: @ZachKauffman: it's the same data, it's just the difference between interpreting it as signed or unsigned.

Comment: @ZachKauffman Yes, to display a Go `byte` value in a signed fashion, just convert it to `int8`. See edited answer.

Comment: Awesome! Guess I need to brush up on my fundamentals a bit (pun intended). It looks like changing my return from `base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(h.Sum(nil))` to `hex.EncodeToString(h.Sum(nil))` in the Go version solved the problem.

Comment: @ZachKauffman Base64 and hex encoding are quite different things (giving completely different result). So basically the long -> byte array conversion is right in your case, but in your examples the `counter` value was different.