# how read binary data in go?(smartcard) convert code to java

Tags: java, go

I need convert the following code to Java programming language. What does mean []byte{}? What is type uint8?

```
func int8ToByte(int_val int) byte {
    buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
    err := binary.Write(buf, binary.LittleEndian, uint8(int_val))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("binary.Write failed:", err)
    }
    return buf.Bytes()[0]
}
```

Comment: I recommend you to follow a go tutorial, that stuff sounds pretty basic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[]byte{}` is a [composite literal](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals) which creates an empty byte slice (of type `[]byte`). The `uint8` type is an unsigned integer type whose size is 1 byte. In Go the type `byte` is an alias for `uint8`, so `byte` and `uint8` are equivalent and completely interchangeable.

I don't know who wrote your `int8ToByte()` function, but that seems like an obfuscation. All it does is it returns the least significant byte of its argument, which is nothing more than a simple [conversion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions) from `int` to `byte`:

```
byte(int_val)
```

See this Go example:

```
func main() {
    fmt.Println(int8ToByte(0x01))
    fmt.Println(int8ToByte(0x0102))
    fmt.Println(int8ToByte(-1))

    var i int
    i = 0x01
    fmt.Println(byte(i))
    i = 0x0102
    fmt.Println(byte(i))
    i = -1
    fmt.Println(byte(i))
}

func int8ToByte(int_val int) byte {
    buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
    err := binary.Write(buf, binary.LittleEndian, uint8(int_val))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("binary.Write failed:", err)
    }
    return buf.Bytes()[0]
}
```

It outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/4RViyUaH2QH)):

```
1
2
255
1
2
255
```

To achieve the same in Java, you again just have to convert the `int` number to `byte`:

```
 public static void main(String []args){
    int i = 0x01;
    System.out.println((byte)i);
    i = 0x0102;
    System.out.println((byte)i);
    i = -1;
    System.out.println((byte)i + " " + String.format("%x", (byte)i));
 }
```

This outputs:

```
1
2
-1 ff
```

Note the difference: Java's `byte` is signed, it has a valid range of `-128..127`, while Go's `byte` is unsigned, its valid range is `0..255`. But the binary representation of both outputs are the same. For details, see [Java vs. Golang for HOTP (rfc-4226)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47797100/java-vs-golang-for-hotp-rfc-4226/47797161#47797161).