# Java and Go hash value with sha256 is different

Tags: java, go, sha256

I'm trying to generate hash with same algorithm (sha256) for same input in Java and Go. Interestingly I'm getting two values. Any Explanation is appreciated and I need to generate same hash generated in Java in Go.

Java code:

```
public byte[] sha256Hash(byte[] content) {
        try {
            MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
            return digest.digest(content);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage(),e);
        }
    }
byte[] to ="AA".getBytes();
byte[] shaed = sha256Hash(to);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(shaed));
```

Java Output:[88, -69, 17, -100, 53, 81, 58, 69, 29, 36, -36, 32, -17, 14, -112, 49, -20, -123, -77, 91, -4, -111, -99, 38, 62, 126, 93, -104, 104, -112, -100, -75]

Go:

```
fmt.Println(sha256.Sum256([]byte("AA")))
```

Go Output:[88 187 17 156 53 81 58 69 29 36 220 32 239 14 144 49 236 133 179 91 252 145 157 38 62 126 93 152 104 144 156 181]

Comment: What do you mean different? The printed decimal bytes?

Comment: If you print a byte array in Java you don't get anything useful. You get `[B@` followed by a hashcode. It doesn't tell you the **contents** of the byte array, which is what's significant.

Comment: And also Java's `byte` is signed while Go's `byte` is unsigned: see in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47797100/java-vs-golang-for-hotp-rfc-4226/47797161#47797161). Print them as hexadecimal values, and then they should match.

Comment: @khelwood I have used Arrays.tostring() to print java output which I forget to post. Even with this its different

Comment: Do include your outputs. Also have you read my linked answer?

Comment: @khelwood added output

Comment: Then this is what I suspected: it's a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47797100/java-vs-golang-for-hotp-rfc-4226/47797161#47797161).

Comment: yep thanks, @khelwood you are correct. sadly I already got minus rating eventhough this is valid question

Answer (score 1):

you are not converting byte to hexadecimal.

```
  import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;
 class GetHash{

public static String generateHash(String pass) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException{
    
    MessageDigest sha=MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
    
    byte[] b=sha.digest(pass.getBytes());
    
    return DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(b);

 }}
```

use DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(b) method to convert byte to hexadecimal string

or  use this link  for more methods
[How do you convert a byte array to a hexadecimal string, and vice versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311165/how-do-you-convert-a-byte-array-to-a-hexadecimal-string-and-vice-versa)

Comment: Why do you link a C# question when this is about Java and Go?

Comment: those methods works in java too

Comment: The syntax is different. There's a similar question in Java, why don't you include that?