# TOTP / HOTP / HmacSHA256 with unsigned bytes key in Java

Tags: java, cryptography, hmac, one-time-password, totp

As we can see from the following questions:

[Java HmacSHA256 with key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46988540/java-hmacsha256-with-key/51933235)

[Java vs. Golang for HOTP (rfc-4226)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47797100/java-vs-golang-for-hotp-rfc-4226)

, Java doesn't really play nicely when using a key in a TOTP / HOTP / HmacSHA256 use case. My analysis is that the following cause trouble:

- `String.getBytes` will (of course) give negative byte values for characters with a character value > 127;
- `javax.crypto.Mac` and `javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec` both externally and internally use `byte[]` for accepting and transforming the key.

We have acquired a number of [Feitian C-200 Single Button OTP devices](https://www.ftsafe.com/Products/OTP/Single_Button_OTP), and they come with a hexadecimal string secret which consist of byte values > 127.

We have successfully created a PoC in Ruby for these tokens, which works flawlessly. Since we want to integrate these in [Keycloak](https://www.keycloak.org), we need to find a Java solution.

Since every implementation of TOTP / HOTP / HmacSHA256 we have seen makes use the `javax.crypto` library and `byte[]`, we fear we have to rewrite all the used classes but using `int` in order to support this scenario.

Q: Is there another way? How can we use secrets in a HmacSHA256 calculation in Java of which the bytes have values > 127 without having to rewrite everything?

---

**Update**

I was looking in the wrong direction. My problem was that the key was represented a String (UTF-16 in Java), which contained Unicode characters that were exploded into **two** bytes by `getBytes()`, before being passed into the `SecretKeySpec`.

Forcing `StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1` on this conversion fixes the problem.

Comment: Java crypto treats the bytes as unsigned and works fine, and has worked fine for billions of users for decades; see my new answer to your first linked question which demonstrates this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Signed vs. unsigned is a presentation issue that's mainly relevant to humans only. The computer doesn't know or care whether `0xFF` means `-1` or `255` to you. So no, you don't need to use ints, using `byte[]` works just fine.

This doesn't mean that you can't break things, since some operations work based on default signed variable types. For example:

```
byte b = (byte)255;    // b is -1 or 255, depending on how you interpret it
int i = b;      // i is -1 or 2³² instead of 255
int u = b & 0xFF; // u is 255
```

---

It seems to throw many people off that Java has only signed primitives (`boolean` and `char` not withstanding). However Java is perfectly capable of performing cryptographic operations, so all these questions where something is "impossible" are just user errors. Which is not something you want when writing security sensitive code.

Comment: Excellently written. Note that addition and subtraction modulo 256 work exactly the same for signed or unsigned values. 127 + 1 = -128 and 127 + 1 = 128 are identical when you look at the bits: 0x7F + 0x01 = 0x80. That 0x80 can mean -128 or 128, so no problem at all. That's one of the nice things about the *two-complement* way of using negative values which each and every CPU uses nowadays. Just like bytes are always 8 bits nowadays :)

Comment: ITYM (IHYM!) Java has only >>signed<< primitives if you ignore `char` and `boolean`

Comment: @Kayaman Thanks for the explanation and pointers. I will revisit my usecase to see why I was led to this conclusion and follow up here.

Comment: @ChrisBrandhorst at least you don't need to write your own crypto framework :)

Comment: @Kayaman Indeed :) My problem lied in the source of the key, a String containing Unicode characters of which the conversion to byte array was incorrect. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Don't be afraid of Java :) I've tested dozens tokens from different vendors, and everything is fine with Java, you just need to pickup correct converter.

It's common issue to get bytes from String as getBytes() instead of using proper converter. The file you have from your vendor represent secret keys in hex format, so just google 'java hex string to byte array' and choose solution, that works for you.

Hex, Base32, Base64 is just a representation and you can easily convert from one to another.

Answer (score 0):

I've ran into absolutely the same issue (some years later): we got **Feitian devices**, and had to set up their server side code.
None of the available implementations worked with them (neither php or java).

**Solution**: Feitian devices come with seeds in hexadecimal. First you have to decode the seed into raw binary (e.g. in PHP using the *hex2bin()*). That data is the correct input of the TOTP/HOTP functions.
The *hex2bin()* version of java is a bit tricky, and its solution is clearly written in the question of the OP.

(long story short: the result of hex2bin you have to interpret with StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1, otherwise some chars will be interpreted as 2 bytes utf-16 char, which causes different passcode at the end)

```
String hex = "1234567890ABCDEF"; // original seed from Feitian

Sring secretKey = new String(hex2bin(hex), StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
Key key = new SecretKeySpec(secretKey.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1), "RAW");
// or without String representation:
Key key = new SecretKeySpec(hex2bin(hex), "RAW");
```